# Can I export multiple named exports in a named set without affecting call to variable?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have constants file with:

```
export const VAR1 = 'VAR1';
export const VAR2 = 'VAR2';
export const VAR3 = 'VAR3';
export const VAR4 = 'VAR4';
export const VAR5 = 'VAR5';
export const VAR6 = 'VAR6';
export const VAR7 = 'VAR7';
export const VAR8 = 'VAR8';
export const VAR9 = 'VAR9';
export const VAR10 = 'VAR10';
```

Some of the constants can be used separately and some I use as a specific set in several files, like:

```
import {VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR8, VAR9, VAR10} from './constants'
```

Can I have several exports in a set, so that they can be easily imported in multiple files, but be called using same names? For example:

```
export set1 = [VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR8, VAR9, VAR10];
```

And then in file:

```
import set1 from './constants';

if(input === VAR1) doSomething()
```

So I want to be able to import multiple named exports in one go, but still keep ability to simply call them just by their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, though your export and usage are incorrect, it would be (but keep reading):

```
export const VAR1 = "VAR1";
export const VAR2 = "VAR2";
// ...

export const set1 = [VAR1, VAR2, /*...*/];
// or probably more usefully, as an object:
export const set1 = {VAR1, VAR2, /*...*/};
```

Then the import and usage would be:

```
import { set1 } from "./constants";

// If you use an array:
if (input === set1[0]) doSomething();
// Or if you use an object:
if (input === set1.VAR1) doSomething();
```

Note that in both cases, **there is no ongoing link** between the exported `VAR1` (etc.) and the exported `set1`.  But since `VAR1` and such are constants, that doesn't matter, their values never change. (It *would* matter if they weren't constants, because the set would only have their value as of when the export occurred, not their updated value later.)

---

Or using a default export (I don't like them, but some people do):

```
export const VAR1 = "VAR1";
export const VAR2 = "VAR2";
// ...

export default [VAR1, VAR2, /*...*/];
// or probably more usefully, as an object:
export default {VAR1, VAR2, /*...*/};
```

Then the import and usage would be:

```
import set1 from "./constants";

// If you use an array:
if (input === set1[0]) doSomething();
// Or if you use an object:
if (input === set1.VAR1) doSomething();
```

---

Or you could leave the exports alone and do a module namespace import:

```
import * as set1 from "./constants";

if (input === set1.VAR1) doSomething();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it so I can still call it like so: `if (input === VAR1) doSomething();` instead of `set1.VAR1`?

Comment: maybe destructuring?

Comment: @Alyona - Nothing that would be better than just using the named exports you already have. (In loose mode you could have used the `with` statement, but modules are strict by default and there's a reason `with` was deprecated.)